# jQuery to append content to div by id not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Im trying to append content from a json-encoded result of an AJAX call as follows:

```
$.each(results["data"], function(i, result){
    $("#resultset").append = result["name"];
    console.log(result["name"]);
});
```

When executing the code, console.log records the names of the data elements, but the div remains empty. Not sure why.

HTML:

```
<div id="resultset">
</div>
```

Comment: Your id in HTML is different to the Js

Comment: I see the HTML was different, but it was the same in my code. The issue was the function call, not setting a property. Thanks to nnnnnn who pointed me out to my error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[`.append()`](https://devdocs.io/jquery/append)** is a function that you call, not a property that you assign a value to, so:

```
$("#resultset").append(result["name"]) ;
```

(Depending on what is actually in `result["name"]` you may also want to append some `<br>` elements, or wrap each result in a `<p>` element or something...)

Also you JS is trying to use the id `"result_set"` but in your html the id is `"resultset"` without the `"_"`.

Comment: @nnnnnn - thanks for pointing out my error. I didn't realize this worked differently than setting innerHTML in Javascript. Thanks. You answered my question.

Answer (score -1):

You've specified the id to be targeted in your JQuery as `result_set`, but the id in the html is `resultset`.

You need to make sure these match up exactly!

Comment: I see that I did in the question and appropriately fixed the question. This question was sanitized poorly, my bad. The real issue was I was calling a function and not setting a property. Thats my error.